# How to rename a file being uploaded

Tags: php, file, upload, rename

I'm trying to rename a file that's uploaded.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath . $newfilename)
```

What I get is to have `$newfilename` appended to the original file name, not to replace it.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

```
$UploadImage=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$EmpName=explode(".",$UploadImage);
$Exp=$EmpName[1];
$ImageName="upload/".md5(date("d-m-y H:i:s")).".".$Exp;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$ImageName);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have no issue in generating a new name, my issue is when I upload the file: the new name is appended to the original one.

i.e. oldname.jpgnewname.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was storing dir+filename in [$targetFilePath] ^^;